# Config typescript as Node project

Tags: typescript

I have this simple class

```js
class Blob { }
```

But when I compile it with typescript is telling me that

```sh
  ../../../usr/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:2537:11
    2537 interface Blob {
                   ~~~~
    'Blob' was also declared here.
  ../../../usr/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:2546:13
    2546 declare var Blob: {
                     ~~~~
    and here.
```

But my project is a Node based one! It is not web frotend project, so I dont need any **dom** types!

Edit tsconfig

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "allowJs": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "strict": true,
    "rootDirs": [],
    "types": ["node"],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "inlineSourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,  
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Post your `tsconfig.json` here so we can see what's wrong.

Comment: You're using target `es5` and not passing anything in `lib` so you're importing `DOM,ES5,ScriptHost` automatically. Try setting `"lib": []` inside your `compilerOptions` and see what happens.

Comment: amazing, much thanks!

Comment: I've updated my answer then, I would appreciate if you could accept it. ️

Answer (score 0):

You're using target `es5` and not passing anything in `lib`, so you're importing `DOM, ES5, ScriptHost` by default.

Try setting `"lib": []` inside your `compilerOptions` and it should work.

More info about this whole thing [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html).

Comment: Updated the answer.